# Why am I not getting any console output when I use large numbers of type Long in Java?

Tags: console

I'm writing code in Eclipse to find the prime factors of a given number. When I input a smaller number of type Long, I'm able to get an output with all the prime factors. However, when I use a large number (trying to do 600851475143L for project Euler), the console window doesn't display, and when I manually display the window there's no output. What can I do to get the result to show? Below is my code in case it's causing the problem, and the inputted number is in the main method. What can I do to get the output to show?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Prime {
    public static List<Long> getFactors(Long number) {
        List<Long> factors = new ArrayList<Long>();
        for (Long i = (long) 2; i < number/2 + 1; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0 ) {
                factors.add(i);
            }

        }
        return factors;

    }

    public static void getPrimeFactors(Long x) {
        List<Long> primes =  new ArrayList<Long>();
        for (int n = 0; n < getFactors(x).size(); n++) {
             boolean prime = true;
             Long y = getFactors(x).get(n);
             int factor = 2;
             while ( prime == true && factor < y/2 + 1) {
                 if (y % factor == 0) {
                     prime = false;
                 }
                 else {
                     factor++;
                 }
             }
             if (prime == true) {
                 primes.add(y);
             }          
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(primes.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Long y = 600851475143L;
        getPrimeFactors(y);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's possible the getPrimeFactors method is taking too long to run so it never gets a chance to display the window. Maybe try creating a separate thread to execute the getPrimeFactors if there is a possibility it will be computationally intensive and freeze the UI.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the helpful reply. I also thought maybe the runtime was too long. How can I create another thread?